# Is there a library that would provide time delta functionality?

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

Is there a JavaScript library that would provide functionality of a "time difference" object?

For example, let's say I have:

```
time1 = Date(...)
time2 = Date(...)

timeDelta = time2 - time2
```

By default that just gives me milliseconds, which I can work with, but it would be nice to already have something available so I dont have to re-invent the wheel. What I'm shooting for is something like this:

```
timeDelta.hours // would give the number of hours between time2 and time1
time1 + timeDelta // would equal time2
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Necro Post!

http://momentjs.com/

You're welcome.  :P

Answer (score 4):

Try this: http://www.datejs.com/

Comment: Thats a good library but they don't officially support (or document) their time span object - you have to dig it out in their svn.